# How can I use the left and right arrow keys to navigate between elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a set of custom directives (each configured as an element). What I wanted to see if it was possible was to create a keyboard navigation (left and right arrows) that allows the User to switch focus between elements.

Ideally, I'm looking into having 2 functions working.

1. User uses left/right arrows to highlight (CSS: border:yellow) the current element
2. User hits space/enter to select that element

Answer (score 2):

the function keydown will work.

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        console.log('left')        
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        console.log('right')
    } 
});
```

number 37 is a keycode which refers to the left key, 
number 39 is a keycode which refers to the right key. 
So basically each key has a different key code.